# Как добавить русскую мнемоническую раскладку клавиатуры в Mac OS?

Tags: macos, mac, macbook

Где я могу скачать русскую мнемоническую клавиатуру для Mac OS?

Comment: Разве её нет в настройках?

Comment: @AlexeyTen нет.